# create-react-app vulnerabilities

Tags: reactjs, bash, npm

¡Hola!
Mi problema es que siempre que utilizo create-react-app

```
npx create-react-app app
```

Me devuelve 80 moderate severity vulnerabilities :(
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ejecutar `npm audit fix` soluciona los problemas.

Es posible que tu versión de node influya en los paquetes compatibles, entre más antigua más vulnerable y más advertencias tendrás.